# The worlds simplest vue.js/vuefire/firebase app. But can't read value

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuefire

Vue.js is a bit of a life style change for a sql programmer, but getting there. Here I use vuefire as per specs, even manually inserting the correct key from my one record, one field Firebase DB to test it out. Yet see nothing returned or displayed.

Love to know how to do that! And fill in my one value form. From there the sky's the limit I'm sure. Thanks for any help.

ERROR MESSAGE: vue.common.js?e881:481 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: residentsArray is not defined"

```
 <template>

    <div class="edit">

    <div class="container">
      <p style="margin-bottom:10px;font-weight:800;">EDIT RECORD</p><br>

      <form id="form" v-on:submit.prevent="updateResident">

        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label for="first_name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" v-model="currentResident.name">
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add New Resident">
      </form>

    </div>  

  </div>

</template>

    <script>

    import firebase from 'firebase'

    let editConfig = {
    apiKey: "123456789",
    authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "my",
    storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1234567890"
  };

  var firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(editConfig, "Edit")
  var db = firebaseApp.database()

  let residentsReference = db.ref('residents')

  export default {
    name: 'Edit',
    mounted() {
      this.currentResident.name = residentsArray.name;
    },
    firebase: {
      residentsArray: residentsReference.child('-KpzkbA6G4XvEHHMb9H0')
    },
    data () {
      return {
        currentResident: {
          name: ''
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      updateResident: function () {
        // Update record here
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have an export of your firebase if it's not huge/sensitive?

Comment: hi, if i don't solve it today. I'll post online. It has to be something simple I'm sure. Similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995450/vue-js-2-with-firebase-crud-example?rq=1

Comment: If you put `console.log(this.$firebaseRefs.residentsArray)` as the first line of your `mounted` how, what does it log?

Comment: Returns: U {u: Qg, path: E, m: lf, Nc: false, then: undefined…}
Nc
:
false
catch
:
undefined
m
:
lf
path
:
E
then
:
undefined
u
:
Qg
database
:
(...)
key
:
(...)
parent
:
(...)
ref
:
(...)
root
:
(...)
__proto__
:
X

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2RUot    Has the debug info and firebase info. down to one record, one field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `residentsArray.name` to `this.residentsArray.name` in your `mounted` hook.

One more thing: You don't need `mounted` for this.
I'd just make a `computed` for this which return `this.residentsArray.name`. With this, you won't have any binding problems.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the [README](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire) on the `vuefire` Github, it looks like you need to refer the properties of your `firebase` object via `this.$firebaseRefs`:

```
mounted() {
  this.currentResident.name = this.$firebaseRefs.residentsArray.name;
},
```

Comment: Gave it a try, not working. ERROR: "ReferenceError: currentResident is not defined"  Seems defined to me. But at least the first error message is gone.

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing `this.currentResident` and not just `currentResident`?

Comment: this.currentResident.name = this.$firebaseRefs.residentsArray.name; console.log("this.currentResident.name", this.currentResident.name)

> Edit.vue?abe2:130 this.currentResident.name undefined

Comment: And now this one too:

Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: I believe the way the firebase reference is defined, `residentsArray: residentsReference.child('-KpzkbA6G4XvEHHMb9H0')` is going to return array. That means `this.$firebaseRefs.residentsArray.name` will be `undefined`. I suspect you may want to use `asOjbect`.

Comment: Yes, I am only returning one record. 

>>> Have 13 name:value "fields"

This what the debugger shows: >>>>
residentsArray:Array[13]

And #7 returns the correct value: >>>
7:Object
.key:"name"
.value:"Edward Potter"

Now figuring out where to update my code. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: this seems close. updated: >>>>  this.currentResident.name = this.$firebaseRefs.residentsArray.name; TO >>>> this.currentResident.name = this.$residentsArray.name;  Still not working, but feel it's close. Reference here, he also mentions "the life cycle", and that seems to have something to do with it, but assuming after mount(), that's the last phase. Everything should be loaded by then.

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/access-vuefire-result-object-with-javascript/6569/3